# Questions with multiple questions.

Tags: discussion

There are posts on meta about *multiple "exercises"* on a same question. This post is meant to address a question with multiple sub-questions on the same subject.

It is often the case (although unfortunately not often enough) that users show the process which they underwent when thinking about a given problem. But it seems that, sometimes, even this can be a little detrimental to the question itself. I give some examples before further exposing my point:

[First example (Read before edit)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1480101/a-line-is-simply-connected-but-a-circle-is-not-does-this-mean-that-the-one-poin#comment3014175_1480101)

[Second example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1481065/difference-between-mathbbtn-and-sn-and-applications-to-dynamics-euler)

What happens in both questions is that there are multiple questions on the body of the post, and it is quite hard to pinpoint exactly what the user wants and quite sincerely this style of question is rather repelling to answer (at least for me).

Is this an issue, or is this feeling particular to me? If this is an issue, how to properly address it? (Note that I tried to address it by leaving comments.)

Comment: You can [link to specific revisions](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1480101/1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> quite hard to pinpoint exactly what the user wants

There's a closing reason exactly for that:

[image: closing reason]

(Aside: it would be great if the How to Ask page contained some math-specific advice; I believe a Community Manager would make it mod-editable if we knew what to put there.)

Comment: Nice, that really addresses my question. Silly of me to oversee this. Thank you.

But I should note that I feel like there are two "kinds" of "unclearness". One when the question is something like "Can two different bases on a given vector space be multiples of one another", and the one I mentioned in this question.

Comment: True; one can be unclear by saying too little, or by saying way too much.